# Glue and For to many models with Automl - R

Tags: r, for-loop, automl, r-glue

I want to reproduce this code:

```
X_train_model1 <- data.table::fread("datasets_atualizados/dataset_y1.csv") %>% 
  h2o::as.h2o()

X_train_model2<- data.table::fread("datasets_atualizados/dataset_y2.csv") %>% 
  h2o::as.h2o()

#Model construction (20 different models)
model_automl <- h2o.automl(x = 1:11, y = 12, training_frame = X_train_model1,
                max_models = 20, seed = 1)

# Save the model
# In this case the leaderboard model is StackedEnsemble_AllModels
model_path <- h2o.saveModel(object = model_automl@leader, path = "models", force=TRUE)
```

Look like this:

```
for (i in 1:2) {

  #Exec the model
  model_automl <- h2o.automl(x = 1:11, y = 12, training_frame = glue::glue("X_train_model", {i}),
                               max_models = 20, seed = 1)
  #Saving the model
  h2o.saveModel(object = model_automl@leader, 
                path = paste0("models", i),
                force=TRUE)
}
```

I sincerely already tried different forms, but I don't conclude this code.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `{i}` is in the wrong place in your code, should be inside the string:

```
for (i in 1:2) {

  #Exec the model
  model_automl <- h2o.automl(
    x = 1:11, 
    y = 12, 
    training_frame = get(glue::glue("X_train_modelo{i}")),
    max_models = 20, 
    seed = 1
  )

  #Saving the model
  h2o.saveModel(object = model_automl@leader, 
                path = paste0("models", i),
                force=TRUE)
}
```

I understand that you have multiple `X_train_modelo` objects, so you will need to use `get()` to refer to them by name.

Comment: Yes, they are multiple models. I did the replacement, but it still doesn't work.